# Truffle console.log is not working

Tags: truffle, console

I've installed Truffle by npm, and running testrpc, but console.log is not working in Truffle console. A simple console.log('test'); do nothing. Any idea?

Comment: which truffle version are you using, which testrpc version are you using, what's your operating system, can you provide sample code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete answer, but I believe it has to do with the console's automatic resolution of javascript promises. For example,

```
Contract.deployed().then(instance => instance.contract)
```

the truffle console will actually wait for the final .then promise to resolve and will then print `instance.contract`. That said, I would imagine that

```
new Promise(() => console.log('test'))
```

would work, or even

```
new Promise(() => 'test')
```

but they don't for me. I don't know enough about promises or the truffle console to understand why that doesn't work. Hopefully this gets fixed in the future. For now, you can do

```
Contract.deployed().then(() => console.log('test'))
```

or

```
Contract.deployed().then(() => 'test')
```

as workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

in the [Testing Your Contracts](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/testing-your-contracts.html#command)

Please try it if your file location is `/test/contract.js`

```
$ truffle test ./test/contract.js
```